# Compiling early C, with arguments declaration under the function name

Tags: c

I found some early *C* sources code, that I wrote, in the days I was beginning *C*, in 1987.

*C* is written with declarations of this kind:

```c
myFunction(c, v)
char c;
int v;
{
   ...
}
```

And I wonder if there is still a compiler available on *Linux* today (I'm on *Debian 10*) able to compile such old code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both `gcc` and `clang` do it with `-std=c89`.

Other pre-ANSI K&R C features may not work, or need options and tricks.

Especially, assuming that you can write to literal strings does not work (neither `gcc` nor `clang` supports `-fwrite-strings` anymore).